# Diferença entre JsViews e JsRender?

Tags: javascript

Comecei a brincar recentemente com templates e acabei me deparando com JsViews e JsRender, já fiz algumas pesquisas a respeito mas ainda não consegui entender muito bem as principais diferenças entre ambos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JsView é uma lib de data bind, enquanto o JsRender é uma lib de template.

O JsRender renderiza HTML usando um modelo, enquanto o JsViews que é construído sobre o JsRender, permite o two way data bind.

https://www.jsviews.com/